# Minimizing a Boolean Expression

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

From a 3 variable K-map I get the following expression: BC + B!C! *!=not

I know that a + a!b = a, so does this mean that BC + B!C! = B + C?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood something.

a + a!b = a or (a! and b), which is not equal to a, because if a=0 and b=1, you have a + a!b = 0 + 0!1 = 0+1*1=0+1=1 (!=a=0)

Similarly, for BC+B!C!=B+C, if you write the truth table, you will see that it is not equal :
B=0,C=0 : BC+B!C!=0*0 + 1*1=1, but B+C = 0+0=0 : the equality doesn't hold already

So I think either you understood something wrong, or there are some additional hypothesis on a, b and c you forgot to tell us (ie some problem specific relations)

Answer (score 1):

> \$a + \bar ab = a\$

No, this is incorrect.  The correct syntax is \$a + \bar ab = a + b\$.

Simplified: \$a + \bar ab = a (1 + b) + \bar ab = a + ab + \bar ab = a + b (a + \bar a) = a+b\$

It is called redundancy.  The \$ \bar a \$ in the \$ \bar ab \$ term is redundant since the \$a\$ term exists.

The origional expression is true if a=0&b=1 OR a=1, which makes a=0 in the first term irrelevant. Expression is true if a=0&b=1 OR a=1&b=1.

Similarily \$BC + \bar B \bar C \ne B + C\$, because they are unique terms.

The results from a K-Map (typically) cannot be simplified.  The exception being XOR and XNOR (which are not true boolean algebra functions).  *Which is a clue*.

[Laws and Theorems of Boolean Algebra](https://wulflemm.com/misc/boolean/boolean.html)

Comment: Thank you for explaining that.  That was very helpful.